# jQuery plugin will use default options instead of user defined options

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a plugin with a update method, which is used if a user ads new content to a div(placeholder), at start things go fine, the plugin will use the user defined options of the plugin, but once the user runs the update method it will use the default options instead of the defined options.

Plugin wrapper...

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){

    //"use strict"; // jshint ;_;

    var pluginName = 'myPlugin';

    function Plugin(element, options){

        this.elm     = $(element);
        this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn[pluginName].defaults, options);

        this.init();
    };

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function(){

            // we run this at start...

        },

        update: function(){

            // code that we need when we need to update...

        },

    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function(option) {
        var options = typeof option == "object" && option;

        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var data  = new Plugin($this, options);

            if(!$.data($this, pluginName)){         
                $.data($this, pluginName, data);
            }

            if(typeof option == 'string'){
                data[option]();
            }

        });
    };

    $.fn[pluginName].defaults = {
        name: 'Hank',
        ...
        ...
    };


})(jQuery, window, document);
```

// inline js

```
    $('#container').myPlugin({name: 'NOT Hank...'});

    $('#updatelink').click(function(e){
       $('#container').myPlugin('update');
    }):
```

Comment: You shouldn't run `new Plugin` on already initialized elements. Instead, the plugin's instance should be stored in the element's `.data` so you can reuse it.

Comment: okay but if I do this the plugin update part wont work

Comment: Why not? it should work. http://jsfiddle.net/BkKRN/

Comment: I have used the code from the bootstrap js files now, this works, but the update method wont wrap the newly added element...

Comment: what do you mean by newly added element. The plugin above only works on one element at a time, and the element has to exist at the time of calling the plugin.